# When does the expected value or variance of the $t$ statistic exist?

Tags: t-test, expected-value

The distribution of Student's $t$ statistic is known when the random variable $x$ follows a Normal distribution. Sometimes, however, we apply it to random variables drawn from other distributions. I am curious if there are known conditions, sufficient and necessary, that the expectation of the $t$ statistic, or its variance, are known to exist (*i.e.* be finite).

For example, in the extreme if $x$ were drawn from a Bernoulli distribution, there would be a non-zero probability the sample variance is zero, and thus $t$ is infinite or not defined, and the expectation of $t$ does not exist. So presumably "the sample variance is positive almost surely" is a necessary condition. I am looking for more conditions like this (and ones that are easier to check).

Comment: Potentially helpful reference: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237635690_Ratio_of_Two_Random_Variables_A_Note_on_the_Existence_of_its_Moments

Comment: @ChristianHennig that is exactly the kind of thing I am looking for, I think. I am a bit surprised, however, there is no reference for when moments of the t-stat exist.

Comment: There is a published article [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1402537#metadata_info_tab_contents)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen perhaps I have misread the article, but it does not seem to address the issue of _moments_, instead focusing on the 0.05 and 0.95 quantiles under non-normal $x$.

Answer (score 2):

### The case of independent and identical distributions for the variables $X_i$ in the sample

The (non-central) t-distribution is proportional to the distribution of the inverse of the tangent of the angle of the sample $\vec{x}$ with the diagonal line $x_1 = x_2 = \dots = x_n$.

$$t = \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{\text{tan}(\theta)}$$

The problematic case is when this angle is 0 degrees in which case $\tan(\theta) = 0$ and the inverse is infinite.

#### Discrete distribution

In your example with a Bernoulli distribution you have a discrete distribution and there is a non-zero probability that $\theta = 0$, or that the sample $\vec{x}$ is on the diagonal line.

Whenever that probability is non-zero then the mean of $t$ (and other moments) will be infinite or undefined. This happens with any iid discrete sampling because there is a non-zero probability

$$P(X_1 = X_2 = \dots = X_n) = \sum_{\forall x} P(X=x)^n$$

#### Continuous distribution

One can imagine the distribution of the sample $\vec{x}$ projected onto a sphere of radius $1$ and see how it is distributed near the two points of the intersection with the diagonal.

For continuous distributions, the probability that $\theta = 0$ will be zero (unless you have fully correlated sample), but what also matters is how the density changes in the neighbourhood of $\theta = 0$.

For the expected value to be finite we need to have the second derivative of the distribution of $z = \tan(\theta)$ to be zero in the point $z=0$. Since

$$E[1/z] =  \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{z} f(z) dz + \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{z} f(z) dz$$

...

<sup>To be continued I imagine that we can come up with some distribution that concentrates in one or more values such that for cases with $n = 3$ we do not have a finite mean (unlike the case of a normal distribution). Also when $X$ already has finite mean, then probably $t$ will have a finite mean as well.</sup>

Comment: This is about where I landed. I then thought to try Jensen's Inequality to bound the variance of the $t$ stat, but it goes the wrong way and I could only prove a _lower_ bound on the variance.

Comment: @shabbychef do you follow the intuition in my other post. I have troubles (and lack free time) to write it down more formally, but I feel that it is the square dependency of the area in that third image (in the case of $\nu = 2$ and $n = 3$) that makes the mean become finite and defined.

Answer (score 0):

One way to investigate this is by simulation. Since the question is about existence of moments, we could use some estimator of the tail index of the distribution of the T statistic, which is related to existence of expectation and other moments [a definition of tail index here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307671/is-there-a-closed-form-solution-for-the-tail-index-of-a-gb2-distribution).

For an example I will simulate $N=100000$ times from a uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$. The distribution of the T statistic is

[image]

with a $t_4$-density overlaid. But it is the tail behavior which is most important, which is difficult to judge from such a plot.  Let us try a relative distribution plot, again comparing to the $t_4$:

[image: histogram with overlaid t density]

which indicated heavier tails.  Then let us try the Hill estimator:

[image: Hill estimator plot]

(the lower curve is EPD estimator, see code below). This at least indicates a tail index < 1, so that expectation do not exist, in contrast to the $t_4$.

R code:

```r
sim_Tstat <- function(N, n, rparent=rnorm, mu_0=0) {
  Tstat <- replicate(N, 
                     {x <- rparent(n)
                      t <- sqrt(n)*(mean(x)-mu_0)/sd(x)
                      t})
  return(Tstat)
}

library(ReIns)
library(reldist)

set.seed(7*11*13)

test <- sim_Tstat(1E5, 5, rparent=\(n){runif(n, min=-1, max=1)})

hist(test, prob=TRUE, xlim=c(-5,5), breaks="FD")
plot( \(x) dt(x, df=4), from=-5, to=5, col="red", add=TRUE)

reldist(test, qt(ppoints(1E5), df=4), method="bgk") 

Hill(test[test>0], plot=TRUE)
EPD(test[test>0], add=TRUE)
```

Comment: My suspicion would be that if $x$ is Uniform on $(-1,1)$ then all moments of the $t$ statistic exist. The failure modes I can see would be if the standard deviation of the $x$ does not exist, or if there is positive probability that the sample standard deviation is zero, neither of which would apply in this case.

Comment: That would also be my inclination, but the simulation suggests otherwise ... when I have some time I will investigate further

Comment: I am not sure about the Hill and EPD index part: when I try your code but draw X from a normal distribution, I get similar shaped plots (perhaps it is the scale that is important). I should also say that I suspect the existence may depend on the sample size, since the reference to Celdinik _et al_ referenced in the comments above suggests that a sufficient condition would be that $P\left(s^2 < \delta\right) < \delta^{k+\epsilon}$ for some $k$ and $\delta$ sufficiently small, where $s^2$ is the sample variance.

Answer (score -1):

> The distribution of Student's t statistic is known when the random
> variable x follows a Normal distribution. Sometimes, however, we apply
> it to random variables drawn from other distributions. I am curious if
> there are known conditions, sufficient and necessary, that the
> expectation of the t statistic, or its variance, are known to exist
> (i.e. be finite).

If the observations are normally distributed, the t-statistic follows a t-distribution under the null hypothesis, but note that with many observations it amounts to the standard normal distribution. The "other distributions" you mention for observations are the fairly large category to which the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) can be applied. So the limiting distribution for t-stat is already the standard normal distribution. Therefore, it seems to me that the conditions you mention for the finiteness of the first two moments of t-stat go back to those of the CLT.

> For example, in the extreme if x were drawn from a Bernoulli
> distribution, there would be a non-zero probability the sample
> variance is zero, and thus t is infinite or not defined, and the
> expectation of t does not exist.

Something like this will almost certainly not happen if the data come from Normal, and this is true for any large sample that meets the CLT assumptions.

Finally, the CLT implies convergence of the t-stat to the standard normal distribution, but, as noted in Whuber's comment, the CLT does not imply convergence of the moments. Indeed, convergence in the distribution does not generally imply convergence in the moments. This problem is a weakness of my argument. I will not solve it now; suggestions are welcome.

I can note, however, that even if convergence in the distribution does not imply convergence of moments, it is not true that convergence in the distribution implies or even suggests the absence of convergence of moments.
The problem we are talking about here may be of little relevance in practice, and I suspect that it is.

The rule “convergence in distribution do not imply convergence on moments” is useful also as warning about the fact that some moments may not exist. However, as mentioned above, the CLT is about the convergence of the t-stat with the standard normal distribution. I have a hard time finding an intuitive and concrete case where the t-stat approximates the standard normal distribution, but the mean and variance are significantly different compared to what that distribution should imply. Moreover, even if some cases are shown, they should be pathological and the main message of my proposal can remain.

Comment: If by "TLC" you mean the Central Limit Theorem, then this argument is incorrect.  That theorem tells you nothing whatsoever about moments of the t (or Z) statistic.  But if you don't mean that, what is the "TLC"?

Comment: Yes, I intend Central Limit Theorem. It seems me that if related conditions are meet the t statistic follow a standard normal distribution, therefore its mean and variance are known. Why this is incorrect?

Comment: The t statistic almost never follows a Normal distribution.  In ideal circumstances it follows a Student t distribution.  Those circumstances require that the numerator be Normal with zero mean, the denominator be chi-squared, and the two be independent.  Furthermore, theorems about the limits of *distributions* do not translate to limits of the corresponding *moments.*

Comment: The "ideal conditions" you mention sound to me as quite standard assumptions about the t-stat in the linear regression classical framework. Moreover, the t-Student distribution converges to the Normal distribution with increasing sample size. This convergence holds under much weaker assumptions, and I stated those above. Therefore, your sentence "The t-statistic almost never follows a normal distribution" sounds too strict, if not wrong, to me.

Comment: Too strict in the sense that we can say something like that about all asymptotic results. Regarding your last point " theorems about the limits of distributions do not translate to limits of the corresponding moments ": This is indeed a problem. However, I have a hard time finding an intuitive and concrete case where the t-stat approximates the standard normal distribution, but the mean and variance are significantly different compared to what that distribution should imply.

Comment: Because the question concerns "random variables drawn from other distributions," the onus is on you to characterize the scope of that description and demonstrate that your assumptions are plausible. One is inclined to be doubtful: what, for instance, is the distribution of the t statistic for data that are themselves sampled from a Cauchy distribution?  I think you will be surprised at the result (it is asymptotically *bimodal!*).

Comment: The asker looking for conditions that guarantee existence of second moment for t-stat under non normality of data. I suggest that such conditions meet the TLC assumpions. Your counterexample (datas from Cauchy) do not meet TLC assumpions.

Comment: That still doesn't rescue your conclusion, I'm afraid.  In the question itself it is pointed out there is a problem even with the Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: I noted this problem and already reply in my answer. This problem, and like it, is serious only in small samples. TLC deals with large samples where this problem tend to disappear.

Comment: I will end my participation in this comment thread by reiterating that the CLT does not imply anything about convergence of moments.